# JSON.stringify into Query String Parameter of Request w/out a Body

Tags: json, api, request, query-string

I have a GET Request route which executes a parameterized query. The parameters in this query can take nested JSON objects such as `parentkey.subKey`.

```js
var jsonParam = {
  parentKey: {
    subKey: [1,2,3]
  }
};

axios.get('https://www.example.com/search', {
  params: {
    json: JSON.stringify(jsonParam)
  }
};

// Request Made
// ------------
// https://www.example.com/search?json=%7B%0A%20%20parentKey%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20subKey%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D
```

I'm asking whether it is bad practice to allow a GET Request to take a full JSON object in a single query string parameter.